# Prerequisites and reference for $\ell$-adic cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homology-cohomology

I am currently going through Liu's book in algebraic geometry while working through commutative algebra, supplementing it with Hartshorne's classic text and Ravi Vakil's FoAG. I have taken a standard class in algebraic topology that covered the entirety of chapter 2 of Hatcher and manifolds. I would like to know what kind of prerequisites I would need to learn about $\ell$-adic cohomology and what good reference books are usually recommended to newcomers to the theory.

Comment: It depends if by 'newcomer' you mean someone that wants all the details, or someone that doesn't want to be bogged down in all the details. If you want the former I suggest something like Lei Fu (which is essentially a translation of SGA4 with some organizational differences) and SGA4.5 for the latter. If you want something in between I suggest Milne's book (NOT his online notes).

Comment: Probably something in-between. I will check out Milne's book thanks.